# How to put specific numbers of items from a list in the textbox using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, list-comprehension

I have a list which has more than 250 items in it. I want to put it in the textbox with selenium in python. I have to put 25 list each time. Can you make a loop for me 25 item with 24 COMMA each time?

Code trials:

```
My_List=["400","840","360","700","900","350",....,"340"]
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td/div/input').send_keys(My_list[i])
```

Example input:

```
400,840,360,--->25 item<-----430,350
```

Answer (score 0):

To put specific numbers of items from a list with in a textbox using Selenium and Python, an elegant approach would be to create a *list of list* from the given list using [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as follows:

```
sequence=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print([sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(sequence),3)]) #grouping the list elements in groups of 3 elements
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

---

### Implementation

To implement the above logic in your program, you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
my_list=["400","840","360","700","900","350","340"]
my_list_of_list = [my_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(my_list),3)] # List Comprehensions
for i in range(len(my_list_of_list)):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys(my_list_of_list[i])
    time.sleep(10) # for the sake of displayedness
```